# High quality free mapping service for Germany

Tags: germany, maps

Is there a high-quality free mapping service for Germany comparable to the great [IGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institut_g%C3%A9ographique_national) maps of France available for free on [Geoportail](https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/)?

I am looking for something that can be used to plan hikes and discover new areas.

Comment: you *might* have more luck on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @MarkMayo If it's on-topic here, I'd like to keep it for a while. I can always delete and re-post on GIS.SE later.

Comment: Oh I totally left it open asits still good here, just was a suggestion :D

Comment: "High quality" is open ended and opinion based. Is OpenStreetMap high quality enough?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mapping is done by the federal states (Bundesländer), so you have to look at the respective land surveying office (Landesvermessungsamt).

E.g. for Bavaria, there is the [Landesamt für Digitalisierung,
Breitband und Vermessung Bayern](https://www.ldbv.bayern.de/), and they link to their own mapping site, the [BayernAtlas](https://geoportal.bayern.de/bayernatlas).

You can find links to all Landesvermessungsämter at the end of this [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landesvermessungsamt).

An overview of the mapping sites (2013): [Die Bundesländer und ihre Online-Kartendienste für topografische Karten](http://www.kraftvolle-orte.de/2013/04/linktipp-die-bundeslaender-und-ihre-online-kartendienste-fuer-topografische-karten/).

Comment: Thanks! I think this was the key piece of information for finding good maps.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is something official similar in Germany.
You can use [Kompass](http://www.kompass.de/touren-und-regionen/wanderkarte/), which use OSM data. I don't know where they get the elevation model from though.

Answer (score 3):

As user24582 wrote, official maps are available in many places. The best freely available map data (available online, using smartphone apps or a (Garmin) GPS device) is based on Openstreetmap - crowdsourced maps. In most areas the data is by far better than other online maps, often even better than official maps which tend to be a bit outdated and not so much focused on tourists.

There are many OSM-based themed maps available, specializing on different use cases, such as hiking, car-routing or even horse riding.

For offline use (smartphone, GPS) my personal recommendation would be http://freizeitkarte-osm.de/ .

For online use I recommend https://hiking.waymarkedtrails.org/ which includes many hiking routes.

Here you can find a comparison of different OSM based maps with Google maps to get an impression of the level of detail available:
http://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/#14/50.1096/8.6855&num=4&mt0=mapnik&mt1=google-map&mt2=public_transport&mt3=hike_bike

Comment: I am aware of OpenStreetMap, but I found it unreliable in the past, and in the remote areas where I compared various maps, it had by far the least detail.  Compare [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/43.4677/4.2988) vs [IGN](https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/carte?c=4.298345436244689,43.46897623436274&z=15&l0=GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.MAPS.SCAN25TOUR::GEOPORTAIL:OGC:WMTS(1)&permalink=yes). I can tell you that the IGN one has errors (I've been there), but it is still far better than OSM. I realize this may not be the case in every area. Maybe Germany has a more active OSM community.

Comment: The German community is the most active one world-wide. Give it a try!
It sure depends on the area of the country, but all the interesting places are mapped well, according to my experience.

Comment: German OSM maps even cover the names of forest tracks: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/52.1322/10.5156